# How to click on img tag as per the HTML provided through Selenium and Java?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

How to click on `<img>` as per the HTML:

```
<a aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript: void(0);"> <span class="cat__top-bar__avatar" href="javascript:void(0);"> <img src="assets/modules/dummy-assets/common/img/avatars/1.jpg"> </span> </a>
```

Complete HTML:

```html
<div class="cat__top-bar__right">                        
                    <!----><div class="cat__top-bar__item hidden-sm-down">
                        <div class="dropdown notification-dropdown">
                            <a aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" href="javascript: void(0);" title="unread notifications">
                                <i class="menu-notification-icon icmn-Notification menu-left__icon"></i><!----><span class="badge badge-noti badge-danger"></span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="arrow-up notifications" id="drop-down-arrow"></div>
                            <ul aria-labelledby="" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="drop-down" role="menu">
                                <div class="notification_bar">
                                    <ul>
                                        <li>Notificaitons (1112)</li>
                                        <li><a href="javascript: void(0);">Marks All as Read</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <!---->
                                <!---->
                                <div class="cat__top-bar__activity">
                                 
                                </div>
                                <a class="view-all-notify" href="#/portals/super-admin/all-notifications">View All Notificaitons</a>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="cat__top-bar__item">
                        <div class="dropdown cat__top-bar__avatar-dropdown">
                            <a aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript: void(0);">
                                <span class="cat__top-bar__avatar" href="javascript:void(0);">
                                    <img src="assets/modules/dummy-assets/common/img/avatars/1.jpg">
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <div class="arrow-up profile"></div>
                            
                            <!----><ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" id="profile-drop-down" role="menu">
                                <div class="dropdown-header"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/portals/super-admin/profile"><i class="dropdown-icon icmn-Profile"></i> Profile</a></div>
                                <div class="dropdown-header"><a class="dropdown-item" href="#/admin"><i class="dropdown-icon icmn-Logout-icon"></i> Logout</a></div>                                
                            </ul>
                       
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Where is the code mentioned in the question headline?

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't approved. You can see it now.

Comment: Which drop down element and image you want to click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the *HTML* you have shared you should not invoke `click()` on the `<img>` tag as it has no `onclick` event. Instead you should invoke `click()` on the `<span>` tag. You can use either of the following solutions to perform `click()`:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a.dropdown-toggle > span.cat__top-bar__avatar")).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class='dropdown-toggle']/span[@class='cat__top-bar__avatar']")).click();
  ```

Comment: Thanks a lot, tried both, working perfectly and logged in the web app but still no click on image.

Comment: @RajaSahilMajeed Perhaps I didn't understand your comment which includes `working perfectly` and `still no click`. Can clarify a bit if my solution have worked for you or not?

Comment: @RajaSahilMajeed Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: Thank you very much. The one with cssSelector is working. I am now able to click on image.

Answer (score 0):

use this xpath

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='assets/modules/dummy-assets/common/img/avatars/1.jpg']")).click();
```

also, you can use it with **explicit wait**

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
element = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//img[@src='assets/modules/dummy-assets/common/img/avatars/1.jpg']")))
element.click()
```